# JS postMessage does not work

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

So on subdomain of my domain I have a html file, for example called `file.html`, which also includes  `<script src="https://example.com/script.js">` in itself.

Then, this `script.js` has some listeners connected with this html, and also the function to send messages to parent, which look as follows:

```
v.sendMessageToParent = function (message) {
    var jsonMessage = {
        action: message
    };
    var win = window.frames.target;
    win.postMessage(jsonMessage, '*');
};
v.sendActionMessageToParent = function (action) {
    var jsonMessage = {
        action: 'action',
        type: action
    };
    var win = window.frames.target;
    win.postMessage(jsonMessage, '*');
};
```

Then, on another domain I have an `iframe`, which `src` is `file.html`.

This another domain also has some `<script src="example.com/main.js">`, and I need this `main.js` to listen to messages sent from `script.js`.

In `main.js` I have this code:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("message", messageHandler);
} else {
  window.attachEvent("onmessage", messageHandler);
}
function messageHandler(event) {
  console.log(event.data);
}
```

But I don't get anything. No JS, domain or other errors are shown, just silence in console.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: from MDN window.frames - returns the window itself, which is an array-like object, listing the direct sub-frames of the current window. So, what is this construction window.frames.target?

Comment: I just took this function from somewhere, so... Tried to change to window.parent.postMessage, still got nothing,

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot to name your iframe "target":

```
<iframe src="http://target.com" name="target">

<script>
  var win = window.frames.target;
  win.postMessage("message", *);
</script>
```